# Recreation of tibble::tibble()

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I need to write a function that creates objects similar to `tibble::tibble()`. The function should take a parameter list() = x that contains the columns (dont need to check for type, length of the columns,.. ).

I can’t use `tibble::tibble()` or similar functions like `data.frame()`, `data.table::data.table()`.

I currently am stuck since I can’t figure out how to bind two columns of different types.
I tried collecting the types of the rows to display it in a row and then put the columns together somehow but I still havent figuered out how.

My code looks like the following:

```
library(tibble) #implemented but isnt used
my_tibble <- function(x) {
  ncol <- as.integer(length(x))
  nrow <- length(x[[1]])
  
  y <- list()
  i <- 1
  while (i <= length(x)) {
    y <- append(y, typeof(x[[i]]), length(y))
    i = i + 1
  }
  
}
```

And example output should look like this:

```
my_tb <- my_tibble(list(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3]))
my_tb

A tibble: 3 x 2
x y
<int> <chr>
1   1a
2   2b
3   3c
```

Comment: FYI, I removed info about your `factor()` task because SO questions should focus on just a single problem. Plus it seemed like you weren’t actually asking for help with that part. (You’re free to post a separate question for the other if you like, though you’d need to include more information.)

Comment: Please provide reproducible input as well.

Comment: Suppose you have a variable (or argument) `a=list(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])`. Then you can create an array by doing `do.call(cbind, a)`. If you want your array to admit any data type you can do `do.call(cbind, lapply(a, as.list))`. But the array columns will be lists.

Comment: @RicVillalba, `do.call(rbind,a)` creates a matrix. I suggest explicitly using the frame variant, `do.call(cbind.data.frame, a)` to create a frame, esp since OP seems eager to combine different classes.

Comment: Could you explain a little as to why you cannot use `data.frame`? Maybe there is a more straightforward solution if we have a better understanding of your limitations.

Answer (score 0):

A tibble and a data.frame are essentially just lists with at least one additionaly attribute (row.names") and a special printing method. So here is a very simple implementation of a tibble:

```r
my_tbl <- function(...) {
  out <- list(...)
  class(out) <- c("my_tbl", "data.frame")
  attr(out, "row.names") <- seq_along(out[[1]])
  return(out)
}

print.my_tbl <- function(x) {
  cat("my tibble: ", nrow(x), " x ", ncol(x), "\n")
  cat(colnames(x), "\n")
  cat(paste0("<", sapply(x, class), ">"), "\n")
  for (r in seq_along(x[[1]])) {
    cat(unlist(x[1,]), "\n")
  }
}
```

So now you can use the new function:

```r
my_tbl(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])
#> my tibble:  3  x  2 
#> x y 
#> <integer> <character> 
#> 1 a 
#> 1 a 
#> 1 a
```

This also works with more complicated input:

```r
my_tbl(list(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3]))
#> my tibble:  2  x  1 
#>  
#> <list> 
#> 1 2 3 
#> 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>